# Saving and loading a model in R

Tags: r, r-caret

When working with [caret](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/index.html), how can I save a model after training, and load it later (e.g. in a different session) for prediction?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

A better solution nowadays is to use saveRDS to save and readRDS to read:

```
saveRDS(model, "model.rds")
my_model <- readRDS("model.rds")
```

This lets you to choose a new name for the object (you don't need to remember the name you used when you saved it)

Answer (score 23):

The correct syntax would be to use:

```
save(model, file="model.Rdata")
```

Thereafter, it can be loaded using the load() command.

Comment: Hmm, yeah that is interesting that the other answer went two and a half years unchanged and incorrect.  Haha

Answer (score 11):

The following code assumes that your model's variable name is 'model':

```
save(model, "model.RData")
```

This will save your model as "model.RData" in the current working directory. You can find out what the working directory is by issuing the following:

```
getwd()
```

To load it back in, ensure that your model is saved in your working directory and issue:

```
load("model.RData")
```

Comment: it my case I needed to explicitly set file by `save(model, file = "model.RData")`