# R programming storing Model after training

Tags: r, r-caret, ensemble-learning

How to save `caret` trained models so that it can be used later for building **ensemble** models in RStudio?

Comment: Try saveRDS -
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/readRDS

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761496/saving-and-loading-a-model-in-r

Comment: Okay it helped, can saveRDS help me save h20 models ?

Comment: It looks like h2o has its own function http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/save-and-load-model.html