# How to move random forest model to shinyapp?

Tags: r, algorithm, shiny, random-forest, decision-tree

I created random forest model in R and how can I move it and implement to my shiny app.
For sure I need to code form for inputing parameters, but it's not a problem. The problem is to save and move the created model to shiny app. Have any ideas? How do you do that?

The function is created simply like this:

```
rf <- randomForest(all_unique_application~., data=train2)
```

Comment: have you looked at  `?saveRDS`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving and loading a model in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761496/saving-and-loading-a-model-in-r)